# Why Node js joi validation is not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

I have implemented joi validation for my project but it's not working for any single field. whatever you pass it's get stored in database it doesn't validate any field even though i did a code for validation
Here is a code for validation

```
import * as Joi from "joi";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { sendError } from "../responseHelper";
import { validationOptions } from "./_index";

export class CountryValidator {

    public async createCountryValidator(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        try {
            const schema = Joi.object({
                id: Joi.number().required(),
                name: Joi.string().required(),
                code: Joi.string().required(),
                status: Joi.number().valid(0, 1).required(),
            });
            schema.validate(req.body, validationOptions);
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            sendError(res, error, error.code, StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my route path

```
adminRoute.route('/country/create')
    .post(countryValidator.createCountryValidator, countryController.createCountry);
```

And on this path I'm posting below data is which totally wrong as per validation but still it accepts all the data and not throwing any validation error

```
{
    "name":"BR1Z",
    "code":100,
    "status":"1"
}
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`schema.validate` returns object with `error` filed (instead of throwing error).

```
...
    const joiRes = schema.validate(req.body, validationOptions);
    if(joiRes.error){
        sendError(res, error, error.code, StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
...
```

see: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.1

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel  for your help and support. This solutions worked for me